# Visual Studio - find the reference from the 'using' statement?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

***Backstory:***  I'm learning to use a new (to me) commercial 3D WPF-based graphics library and I have lots of happily-building, working code to use as examples.     So now I'm trying to write my own code from scratch using that library.    I'm getting a compile error in a "using" statement in a generated (mainwindow.g.cs ) file of the "*(are you missing an assembly reference?)*" variety.

***My Question:***  Since I've got lots of working examples to go from, is there any way in Visual Studio 2013 to examine a "using" statement in one of the examples to see what reference was required to resolve it?  In other words, if the 'using' statement says

```
using Ab3d.DXEngine.Wpf.Samples.Controls;
```

is there any way to see what the working example had to "add reference" for to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the "controls" part of the namespace and selecting "go to definition"? This is in the working example.

Comment: If you use some namespace from assembly which is not referenced in your project - I doubt you can magically find this assembly, because in general assembly name and namespace name are not related to each other. Of course tools like Resharper can help you with that (since they know some dlls you use in other projects, and can scan them for namespaces).

Comment: @ChrisF that wouldn't work, as that namespace might be referenced in both his current project and in a foreign assembly, which definition should it go to?

Comment: @Dispersia. True, which is one reason I posed it as a question in a comment. It's not the solution, but may offer more information which leads to the solution.

Comment: @ChrisF  if I highlight either the entire string or just the "controls" part, "go to definition" is grayed-out but "Peek Definition" is **not** grayed-out.  But it doesn't do much -  that is, the usual window that "peak" pops up doesn't appear, but it **does** highlight the whole string, as if to say the "using" statement **is** the definition.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to add a variable from that namespace into your code, then right click the variable type -> Peek Definition, and at the top it will display what assembly that namespace came from. (As the same namespace can be across multiple assemblies)

Comment: That using statement only occurs in a **generated** file, i.e., mainwindow**.g**.cs, i.e., one that I'm not allowed to edit.  That using statement never actually occurs in the use source code in any of the example code.    The compiler apparently puts it in there because it's referenced in a *xmlns* in the XAML.     That's also why I can't just comment-out the using statement to see what's accessing it and try your idea on that line of code, although I suspect if I did it would say the "definition" is the "using" statement itself, based on what happened when I tried ChrisF's suggestion, above.

Comment: Just add the control that is being referenced in the XAML into code then, anything that you can reference in XAML can be referenced in code as well (or see if you can peek definition in XAML, I mean you should be able to)

Comment: It's just a namespace (xmlns) - nothing in that namespace appears to be actually **referenced** in the XAML - in fact, I solved the immediate problem by just deleting the xmlns line from the XAML, and everything builds fine because the compiler no longer feels compelled to add that "using" to the generated ".g" file.   But I was just hoping to use this situation as a platform to solve the broader "how do I tell what assembly/dll goes with what 'using' statement?" problem.

Comment: @user316117 are you sure it's not actually referenced? It could override if it's set as the default for that page, but if not, just don't even include it in your new application.